# Replace a character in multiple mysql database column

Tags: mysql

Hello I am new to mySQL and i am having trouble trying extracting data from my db by using keywords. I have 2 columns (tags and categories). I have done this before using the LIKE '%keyword%' in my query. The problem is in the db i am using now each keyword is separated with a ';' i would like to know if it is possible to somehow separate each keyword by replacing the semi-colon with a space? Or if it's easier use the same query but instead of using '%' to separate i use semi-colons? sorry if its a newbie question but i am struggling hard with this and really need some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace semi-colon with space ( or any other ) with REPLACE function :

```
UPDATE MyTable SET tags = REPLACE(tags,';',' '), categories = REPLACE(categories,';',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is in the db i am using now each keyword is separated with
>   a ';' i would like to know if it is possible to somehow separate each
>   keyword by replacing the semi-colon with a space? Or if it's easier
>   use the same query but instead of using '%' to separate i use
>   semi-colons?

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (  
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `categories`  varchar(255) NOT NULL  
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample data:

```
insert into `test` values ('tag', 'cat' );
insert into `test` values ('tag', 'cat1;cat2;cat3;' );
```

Example select:

```
select * from `test` where `categories` LIKE '%cat1;%';
+------+-----------------+
| tags | categories      |
+------+-----------------+
| tag  | cat1;cat2;cat3; |
+------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```